# Retrieve all the files whose name start with a number

Tags: bash

The files whose name start with a number could be filtered with regex method

```
$ find . -iregex "./[1-9]+.+"
```

Is it possible to get it done with wildcards,

The failure testing

```
$ ls {0..9}*
ls: cannot access '1*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '2*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '3*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '5*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '6*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '7*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '8*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it is. Let's take this directory as an example:

```
$ ls
1file  4file  7file  8file fileNoNum
```

Now, to list all files (or dirs) that start with a number, you can do:

```
$ ls [0-9]*
1file  4file  7file  8file
```

The shell expansion you used, `{0-9}*` will actually expand to:

```
ls '0*' '1*' '2*' '3*' '4*' '5*' '6*' '7' '8*' '9*'
```

So you will get an error message for every number which isn't the first character of a file in your current directory. Using the glob pattern `[0-9]` instead will avoid these errors.

The reason for this is that shell expansions (`{x..y}`) are expanded by the shell *before* being passed to the program you are calling (`ls` in this case). You can see this in action by using `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ ls {0..9}*
+ ls '0*' 1file '2*' '3*' 4file '5*' '6*' 7file 8file '9*'
ls: cannot access '0*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '2*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '3*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '5*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '6*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '9*': No such file or directory
 1file   4file   7file   8file
```

As you can see above, the patterns actually passed to `ls` were expanded to any matching files before `ls` was called. So the `1*` was converted to `1file`, the `4*` to `4file`, the `7*` to `7file` and the `8*` to `8file`. The rest couldn't be expanded since there were no matching file names, so they were passed to `ls` which tried to list any files matching them, found none, and complained. Just as would have happened had you run them directly:

```
$ ls 9*
ls: cannot access '9*': No such file or directory
```

Compare this to the glob approach:

```
$ ls [0-9]*
+ ls 1file 4file 7file 8file
1file  4file  7file  8file
```

Here, once more, the glob was expanded before calling `ls` but since it is a glob, it was only expanded to matching file names. To further illustrate this, compare what happens when you echo a glob or an expansion:

```
$ echo [0-9]
[0-9]
$ echo {0..9}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

On a separate note, your `find` command doesn't do what you think it does. That will print out all file or directory names *in the current directory* that start with a number, but also all files and sub-dirs of any directories whose name starts with a number. See:

```
$ tree
.
├── 1file
├── 1foo
│   └── file
├── file
└── foo
    └── 1file

$ find . -iregex "./[1-9]+.+" 
./1file
./1foo
./1foo/file
```

The `-iregex` operand of `find` matches the entire file name. So `./foo/1file` was not returned because `./foo` doesn't start with a number and `./1foo/file` was return, although the file name doesn't start with a number because the name of the directory the file is in does start with a number.

To find all files (and only files) that start with a number in this directory or any subdirectories, you can use:

```
$ find . -type f -name '[0-9]*'
./1file
./foo/1file
```